# Where is the stress in the word "commenting"?

Tags: pronunciation

Where is the stress placed in the word *commenting*?  Is it on the first or the second syllable?  How do you pronounce it?

Comment: I am British. **Comm**enting would be my pronunciation.

Comment: It is stressed on the first syllable only. In other words, it's a dactyl. Note that this is different from *commending*, which is stressed on the second syllable.

Comment: @Robusto初夢 I can’t think of a verb where adding *-ing* ever changes the stress pattern. Can you?

Comment: @tchrist: Depends on the dialect, I guess. In some varieties of Southern U.S. speech, for example, the verb *display* stresses the first syllable, but *displaying* stresses the second, or at least makes the stresses equal.

Comment: **Coh**-menting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's stressed on the first syllable. A similar looking word is "commencing", which is stressed on the second syllable.

Answer (score 3):

The stress is on the first syllable, as both descriptive and prescriptive linguists would agree.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a native English speaker, but I think the stress should be on the "m"(which I feel is read more comfortable): [kə'menting].

Comment: As a non-native speaker I thought the stress should be on the "m", too. But, after a look at a dictionary, I released that it's on the first and third syllable.

Comment: @Ed. Brazil: Hi Ed, could you share the dictionary you turned to on this?  I am always using Cambridge online dictionary(http://dictionary.cambridge.org/) but I don't find an entry for "commenting".  Hmm.. I should have done more googling before answering here.. :-)

Comment: It's the participle from the verb [comment](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/comment_2). When adding the "-ing" suffix to a verb to form the participle, the added syllable is always unstressed.

Comment: The dictionary I use is this: dictionary.reference.com. You won't find "Commenting", you can find "Comment". But, if you see that the first syllable is stressed, after adding the suffix the first syllable will still be stressed.

Comment: If you did stress the second syllable of *comment* or *commenting* this would be a sure sign that you are not a native English speaker. Unlike some other languages, in English stress is both lexical (is part of the word and must be memorized) and phonemic (different stress produces different words, even if they have the same consonant sounds: as in *desert* and *dessert*.)